# Why is dropping predictors based on low correlation between predictors and the dependent variable before performing cross validation incorrect?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection

Say I have predictors `X1`, `X2`, ..., `Xn` and a dependent variable `Y`.

I check correlation between the predictors and `Y` and drop predictors that have a low correlation with `Y`. Now I use cross validation between `Y` and the remaining predictors to train a logistic regression model.

What is wrong with this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible problems with doing so, which would end up in a very lengthy answer - I'll just point out two that I think are most important and of which you can use the "buzzwords" to look up anythink still unclear:

1. Dropping features based on their feature-to-target-correlation essentially is a form of feature filtering. It is important to understand that feature filtering *does not necessarily improve predictive performance*. Think e.g. of 2 features in AND or OR configuration to the target variable, and just together will allow for correct prediction of the target variable. Correlation of those features with the target will be low, but dropping them might very well decrease your predictive performance. Besides feature filters there are feature wrappers, with which you essentially use a subset of features with a model and evaluate the predictive performance of the model. So, in contrast to feature filters, which just look at the features and target, feature wrappers look at the actual model performance. BTW: if you end up using feature filters based on feature correlation, you might still not only want to discard features with low feature-target correlation, but also features with high inter-feature correlation (because such features just don't contain much new information at all).
2. If you want to tune your feature selection (e.g. the amount of information/variance you want to preserve in your data, the nr. of features you want to keep, the amount of correlation you allow, etc) and you do this *outside* of your cross validation and resampling approach, you will likely end up with overly optimistic error estimates of your final model. This is because by not including those in the CV process, you will end up selecting one "best" configuration that was not correctly (=independently) estimated, hence might just by chance have been good. So, if you want to correctly estimate the error, you should consider including your feature selection in the CV process too.